# scala code special syntax

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Can anyone explain to me the use of private[streaming] as well as the signification of _ssc (why is the underscore used  in the snippet of code below):

```
private[streaming]
class PubsubInputDStream(
                          _ssc: StreamingContext,
                          val project: String,
                          val topic: Option[String],
                          val subscription: String,
                          val credential: SparkGCPCredentials,
                          val _storageLevel: StorageLevel
                        ) extends ReceiverInputDStream[SparkPubsubMessage](_ssc) {

  override def getReceiver(): Receiver[SparkPubsubMessage] = {
    new PubsubReceiver(project, topic, subscription, credential, _storageLevel)
  }
}
```

Comment: The underscore has no special meaning - i suspect it's just internal name book-keeping for the streaming package

Answer (score 1):

Setting something as private[steaming] means that it is private up to the package streaming (i.e. it is also visible to sub-packages).

The underscore is meaningless in terms of the Scala language, it is probably part of the naming convention of the package author (to designate that it is private)